# Ripples break from Lollipop to Marshmallow

Tags: android

I have a bunch of items that have linear layouts with

```
android:background="@drawable/selector_transparent_semi"
```

Where selector_transparent_semi (values-21) is

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
    <item>
        <selector>
            <item android:drawable="@color/semitransparent_color" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
            <item android:drawable="@color/transparent" android:state_enabled="true"/>
        </selector>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

On an L device, the semitransparent background would show the ripple effect on the spot the user pressed.

After updating to M there appears to be a breaking change where this no longer shows up (overall background highlight works, but no dot and ripple where the user presses).

Anyone know what's going on here and how to fix it?

Edit: Looks like this was M vs L not support lib version.  L shows the ripples differently than M does.  Updated title and description to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears that ripples changed (for M) to be on the release of a press instead of when you press in which explains why this no longer works the way it did.

This seems to do what I want - ripple and change the background if you hold it

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="@color/semitransparent_color">
        <item android:id="@android:id/mask"
            android:drawable="@color/semitransparent_color" />
</ripple>
```