# ?attr/selectableItemBackground effect shows only on longtap

Tags: android, material-design, android-support-library

I've noticed that the effect created by the attribute `?attr/selectableItemBackground` only shows when I long tap the view. But I want it to be shown on every tap.

View is clickable and has on click listener.

How to do that?

Comment: I can not second that. Could you please specify which view you are using? And is there no animation at all on click? Usually it will just be shorter, and the second, darker, circle doesn't fully expand if you just tap / click it, but only if you keep it pressed

Comment: This should not happen, some of your layout code will be very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I've noticed there was a change in the behavior between Lollipop and Marshmallow:

- Lollipop - it would start the ripple on press.
- Marshmallow - the ripple starts on release.

Could that be the issue?

---

I would stick to the device Look & Feel but you could
try this suggested solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34167312/348378

Or use instead a library instead, maybe like this one:

https://github.com/balysv/material-ripple

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by setting the background of a view. First of all you have to make an **item_selector.xml** drawable in drawable and drawable-v21.
For **drawable** folder-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/item_pressed" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/item_pressed" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/item_normal" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/item_normal" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false"/>

</selector>
```

For **drawable-v21** folder-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:attr/colorControlHighlight" >

    <item>
        <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
            <item
                android:drawable="@drawable/item_pressed"
                android:state_focused="true"
                android:state_pressed="true"/>
            <item
                android:drawable="@drawable/item_pressed"
                android:state_focused="false"
                android:state_pressed="true"/>
            <item
                android:drawable="@drawable/item_normal"
                android:state_focused="true"/>
            <item
                android:drawable="@drawable/item_normal"
                android:state_focused="false"
                android:state_pressed="false"/>
        </selector>
    </item>

</ripple>
```

Now all you need to do is put         **android:background="@drawable/item_selector"** in the view tag. For example-

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/traveller_select_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/item_selector"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp">

        <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textTravellers"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
          android:text="@string/passengers"
          android:textColor="@color/baggage_grey"
          android:textSize="12sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now make **item_pressed.xml** in the drawable folder-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
  <solid android:color="@color/filter_bg"/>
</shape>
```

And the **item_normal** in the drawable folder-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without your code, it's hard to know where goes wrong. But since I have just got this implemented, share with you what I've done, and perhaps you just follow, would help you figure out the issue.

In your view that need the click for ripple

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/your_view_id"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content
     android:test="Testing View"
     android:background="@drawable/below_drawable">
```

In your /drawable-v21 folder, you have your below_drawable.xml with content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/your_click_background_color">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectagle" >
            <solid android:color="@android:color/your_mask_color" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

Since the above for Lollipop (v21) only, if you want some impact to your non-lollipop (just show the color, but no ripple). You could have the below in /drawable folder the below_drawable.xml file.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/your_click_background_color" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Hope this helps.