# How to make a selectable List with RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

My Activity is called, so the User should select some Songs, he want to add to a Playlist. How do I make a RecyclerView selectable (the Background-Color should be an Accent Color) and how do I receive the List or Array of the selected Songs from my RecyclerView?

My SelectSongsActivity:

```
public class SelectSongsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Song[] sSongs;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private SelectSongRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        sSongs = (Song[]) bundle.get(Constants.IntentExtra.SONGS);

        Initialize();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_selectsongs, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.mi_Add) {
            Intent i = getIntent();

            i.putExtra(Constants.IntentExtra.SONGS, adapter.getSelectedSongs());

            setResult(RESULT_OK, i);

            finish();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);

        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);

        return super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

    private void Initialize() {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_selectsongs);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new RecyclerViewDivider(this));

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        adapter = new SelectSongRecyclerViewAdapter(sSongs);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

And my RecyclerViewAdapter:

```
public class SelectSongRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SelectSongRecyclerViewAdapter.Holder> {
    private Song[] sSongs;
    private List<Song> selectedSongs;

    public SelectSongRecyclerViewAdapter(Song[] songs) {
        sSongs = songs;

        selectedSongs = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_songview, parent, false);

        Holder holder = new Holder(view);

        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Holder holder, int position) {
        //holder.imvSong.setImageResource(R.drawable.standardartwork);
        holder.txvSongTitle.setText(sSongs[position].getTitle());
        holder.txvSongInfo.setText(sSongs[position].getArtists());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return sSongs != null ? sSongs.length : 0;
    }

    public Song[] getSelectedSongs() {
        Song[] songs = new Song[selectedSongs.size()];

        return selectedSongs.toArray(songs);
    }

    public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        LinearLayout linearLayout;
        ImageView imvSong;
        TextView txvSongTitle;
        TextView txvSongInfo;

        public Holder(View layout) {
            super(layout);

            linearLayout = (LinearLayout) layout;

            imvSong = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.imvSong);
            txvSongTitle = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.adap_txvSongtitle);
            txvSongInfo = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.txvSongInfo);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean when you click on the linearlayout?
What you can do is in the onbindviewholder-

```
holder.linearlayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        selectedSongs.add(sSongs[position]);
      }
    });
```

To display already selected songs in a different color-

```
if (selectedSongs.contains(sSongs[position])) {
  holder.linearlayout.setBackgroundColor(R.color.color_accent);
} else {
  //else as viewholders are reused
  holder.linearlayout.setBackgroundColor(R.color.default_color);
}
```

Comment: it should be like for example the selection in whatsapp contacts (the item is highlighted)

Comment: Then the above code should solve your problems. Also then holder.linearlayout.setBackgroundColor(R.color.default_color); should be replaced by dateHolder.linearlayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.item_selector); 
item_selector- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34467536/attr-selectableitembackground-effect-shows-only-on-longtap/35128898#35128898 my answer